# Total Cost According to Miles Driven

Tags: radicals, slope

> A computer repair person charges 50.00 dollars per hour, plus an additional mileage fee. The charge for mileage varies directly with the square root of the number of miles traveled. If one hour plus 25 miles traveled costs 140.00 dollars, what is the total amount charged for one hour plus 36 miles traveled?

- A) 218.00
- B) 196.92
- C) 179.60
- D) 158.00
- E) 143.60

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? Stating this will help your question to be better received by the community.

Comment: The cost function is at the form $a\sqrt{x} + 50y$ with $x$ being the number of miles traveled and $y$ are hours spent. Try to figure out $a$ and then use the formula for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The charge formula is $$ 50h+k\sqrt m$$ where $h$ stands for number of hours and $m$ stands for number of miles.

For $h=1$ and $m=25$ the charge is $140$, thus $$140= 50 + 5k$$

Solve for $k$ and we get $k=18$

Now if you plug $h=1$ and $m=36$ you find the charge to be  $40+18(6)=158$

Therefore the correct answer is $(D)$

Comment: Thanks for the help! I hate how strict SO users are :(